# Openshift fails and stops building node js application, when trying to deploy

Tags: node.js, openshift, web-deployment, openshift-3

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs application on openshift but it fails after about a minute and when I check the log it stops at the line:

```
---> Building your Node application from source
```

without logging any error.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build is requiring more memory than is allocated by default. You need to increase the amount of memory for the build. This issue, how to confirm that this is the issue, and how to increase the memory allocated are given in the blog post:

- https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-3-questions-answers/#3

In short, try running:

```
oc patch bc/shareit -p '{"spec":{"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'
```